# Building Feature Branches using BitBucket and Jenkins and MSBUILD

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I am attempting to setup a project in Jenkins that can build my teams feature branches for our testing and review process.  The basic flow goes as follows

1. Issue comes in and is assigned to developer
2. Developer creates feature branch for fix and fixes issues
3. Pull Request is create for review
4. Code and feature is reviewed

At this point we would like Jenkins to recognize the branch and have the ability to create a build from the feature branch or pull request.

I have attempted to use the Multibranch Pipeline to recognize the branches with a Jenkinsfile.  This seems to find the branches but I'm not exactly sure of the best process for building the branches.

I apologize for the newbie question, but I am new to the Git/Jenkins world. At this point I am mainly looking for recommendations and/or information sources that will lead me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly possible. We have done it like this:

- A jenkins job `sync-branches` runs regularly and basically consists of a script which looks at the git repository and finds current feature branches; i.e., branches which follow our naming scheme that are not yet merged into `master`. The script will then either create new jenkins jobs as needed, or delete old jobs (if the feature branch has indeed been merged to `master`).
- A second jenkins job `feature-template` is, you guessed it, our template for these automatically created jobs.

Implementing such a script is pretty self-explanatory and should pose no great problem; we did it in a slightly unusual script language so I won't bother to post it here.

The key bits of knowledge are that there is a CLI for Jenkins https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI ; and the actual jobs are configured as one XML file per job. So it is pretty easy to grab that template XML file and substitute a few things (for example, the branch name) before creating a new job with it.